# What is the proper way to use continue?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, syntax, break, continue

I am running into problems accomplishing another iteration after using continue. The goal is to get an integer input that is greater than or equal to 3. I dont want the script to error out on the user, instead I would like to ask for another input.

```
while True:
    try:
        sides = int(raw_input("Marty wants to draw you a shape. How many sides will the shape have?"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Marty needs an integer, try again."
        continue
    if sides < 2:
        print "Marty needs a number greater than 2, try again."
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Does the issue come when using continue twice? Any advice in the proper use of continue would be great. As it stands now, it asks the user for an input. If given anything other than an integer, it asks for another input. If given 2 it does nothing, not even print, let alone try again for an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your use of continue, it's with your evaluation of the input. Rather than what you have, try:

```
if sides <= 2:
    print 'Marty needs a number greater than 2, try again.'
    continue
```

or:

```
if sides < 3:
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! And good to know that it was not a continue issue.